# First and Second Order Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function having both first and second derivatives $f'$ and $f''$  on the interval $(-4,4)$. Show that if $f(0)= f(1)$ and $f(2)=2$ then $f'(a)=1/2$  for some points of $a \in (-4,4)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.  A simple counterexample: the function $f(x) = 2$.  This satisfies all the conditions, but for all $x \in \mathbb R,\, f'(x) = 0$.